# Equivalent WinForm DataGridView code to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I have a data in DataGrid with n Rows, and the DataGrid is ReadOnly. Now my goal is to when I select any row or rows and then press EDIT Button then all the selected rows only becomes ReadOnly = false. so that I want to edit some data in selected row(s). After this when I press the update button then only the selected rows are updated using EntityFramework.
I done this task in WinForm DataGridView. Now I want the same thing in WPF DataGrid.

```
private void editCust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    item.Cells[i].ReadOnly = false;
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Row Is Selected To Edit.");
        }
    }

    private void updateCust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                cutable.Customer_Name = (string)item.Cells[1].Value;
                cutable.Counter = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(item.Cells[2].Value));
                cutable.Buying_Cost = float.Parse(Convert.ToString(item.Cells[3].Value));

                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    item.Cells[i].ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Is Update.");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Row Is Selected To Update.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain whats the logic or whats the motive behind your code, so that we can give you a solution for that for a Datagrid

Comment: Thanks @Learning for the reply.
In WPF, I have a data in DataGrid with n Rows, and the DataGrid is ReadOnly. Now my goal is to when I select any row or rows and then press EDIT Button then all the selected rows only becomes ReadOnly  = false. so that I want to edit some data in selected row(s). After this when I press the update button then only the selected rows are updated using EntityFramework

Comment: whats the name of domain model/table name? in which data will be updated

Comment: I done this task in WinForm DataGridView. Now I want the same thing in WPF DataGrid. See above. I updated the post description and code above. See the updateCust_Click event above.

Answer (score 1):

First convert `DataGridView` to `DataTable` then to `DataGrid`

**For DataGridView to DataTable**

Use this:

```
DataTable myDataTable=(DataTable)(myDataGridView.DataSource);
```

For more reference go through [DataGridView to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295161/how-to-build-a-datatable-from-a-datagridview)

**Now for DataTable to DataGrid**

Use this:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource=myDataTable.DefaultView;
myDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
myDataGrid.CanUserAddRows = false;
```

For more reference go through [DataTable to DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagrid)

Comment for any query

**UPDATE:**

Try to create to your own code and logic, do not depend on direct solutions given by someone.

Well a similar issue I found in StackOverflow[Solved].

Refer to this question [how to edit select row in datagrid in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191766/how-to-edit-select-row-in-datagrid-in-wpf)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want the Eqiavalent WinForm DataGridView code in WPF DataGrid.